# Is gevent pool wait_available thread safe

Tags: python, pool, gevent, green-threads

So I have a function lets say test and gevent pool of size 10.

```
pool.Pool(size=10)
def test():
    pool.wait_available(timeout=0.5)
    pool.spawn(something)
```

If the function test is called by different threads, will it cause any issue. I mean `wait_available`should be thread safe but the `pool.spawn` will it have thread safety/race condition issue. I mean lets say there are already 9 greenlets running and there a couple of requests calling the test function. Both of them will read pool.wait_available which should not block But the pool.spawn right after that will make one of them block.

I just want to make sure that the `pool.spawn` doesn't block for more than the specified timeout period. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

`wait_available` isn't necessary if you're using `spawn` from `pool` because `spawn` will ask for a `lock` in the `Pool`s internal semaphore that is used to track running greenlets. An exception to this is only when you use `apply_async`. I will explain both scenarios here:

```
pool.Pool(size=10)
def test():
    for i in xrange(20):
        log('Processing {}'.format(i))
        pool.spawn(something)
    pool.join()
    log('Done')
```

The output of this shows it will spawn greenlets in groups of 10 since the pool contains space for 10:

```
1531531331: Processing 0
1531531331: Processing 1
1531531331: Processing 2
1531531331: Processing 3
1531531331: Processing 4
1531531331: Processing 5
1531531331: Processing 6
1531531331: Processing 7
1531531331: Processing 8
1531531331: Processing 9
1531531340: Processing 10
1531531340: Processing 11
1531531340: Processing 12
1531531340: Processing 13
1531531340: Processing 14
1531531340: Processing 15
1531531340: Processing 16
1531531340: Processing 17
1531531340: Processing 18
1531531340: Processing 19
1531531349: Done
```

Conversely, if you use `apply_Async` instead of spawn, it will force all the calls to run at the same time. There will be a race condition here for all greeenlets to start execution immediately.

```
1531531357: Processing 0
1531531357: Processing 1
1531531357: Processing 2
1531531357: Processing 3
1531531357: Processing 4
1531531357: Processing 5
1531531357: Processing 6
1531531357: Processing 7
1531531357: Processing 8
1531531357: Processing 9
1531531357: Processing 10
1531531357: Processing 11
1531531357: Processing 12
1531531357: Processing 13
1531531357: Processing 14
1531531357: Processing 15
1531531357: Processing 16
1531531357: Processing 17
1531531357: Processing 18
1531531357: Processing 19
1531531367: Done
```

If you use `wait_available()` at the beginning, you go back to similar behaviour to `spawn`. So, if you are using spawn, you dont need `wait_available()` as they do same check(checking the semaphore to see if there's any room in the pool).

Hope it helps! Gevent is amazing! happy coding!

Comment: So what I want is I don't want the calls to block for more than specified period of time. So lets say that all the 10 greenlets are taken. And a new request comes in. If the previous 10 greenlets keep on running for a while, this new request will be blocked for a long time. I don't want it to be blocked for a long time

Comment: Python is fundamentally single-threaded. What gevent does is to give you a better interface to work with async io. You could increase pool size or spin up multiple pools and alternate between them to avoid blocking requests. Else, there is no way to avoid the block when all the greenlets within a pool are busy. For computationally expensive tasks, multiprocessing(https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) is better.